# Showing success message to User

Tags: android

Recently I've started exploring android, and am not able to understand how to achieve a specific task.

Please find the details below:

There are 2 activities: MainActivity and AddWordActivity. When user clicks on buttons present on MainActivity, he moves to AddWordActivity. From this activity, user can add a word.

After entering relevant details, when user click on add button, I want to redirect user to MainActivity again, and display a text above the MainActivity, like 'Word added successfully'. How can this be achieved? What is the specific name for this approach?

I've been searching this as showing notification, but looks like that is totally a different thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start the AddWordActivity using

```
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

And in MainActivity, implement

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
   if(requestCode==REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
       Toast.makeText(this, "Succes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

To go back from the AddWordActivity  to the MainActivity, use:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

Answer (score 3):

Morning lazy mode: you can simply display a *toast* message and *finish* in **AddWordActivity**

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Word added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
finish();
```

otherwise you will need to start **AddWordActivity** for result and return result to **MainActivity**

In MainActivity

```
public static final REQUEST_CODE = 1;
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE); // # When button clicked

@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
   if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == AddWordActivity.RESULT_OK) // # Will return here when AddWordActivity is finished with a result on intent
   {
       // # TODO : Implement user notification here
   }
}
```

In AddWordActivity

```
public static final RESULT_OK = 8;

// # When the word is added
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

Comment: I was trying to use the Toast message inside button listener your code was not working.
the problem that `this` was not refrening to the context so I did this edit for you code snippet so it can work any where.
`Context context = getApplicationContext(); Toast.makeText(context , "Word added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Answer (score 1):

Start your AddWordActivity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, AddWordActivity.class);
i.putExtra("Value1", "This value one for ActivityTwo ");
i.putExtra("Value2", "This value two ActivityTwo");

Set the request code to any code you like, you can identify the
callback via this code

startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
```

And in MainActivity implement:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
if (data.hasExtra("returnKey1")) {
  Toast.makeText(this, "Success "+"and Intent value:"+data.getExtras().getString("returnKey1"),
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
}
```

Add below into your AddWordActivity:

```
  Prepare data intent 
  Intent data = new Intent();
  data.putExtra("returnKey1", "Swinging on a star. ");
  data.putExtra("returnKey2", "You could be better then you are. ");
  Activity finished ok, return the data
  setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
  finish();
```

Here i provide Intent with some information sharing between the activities. Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

The notification thing could be a simple `toast`. And for your data passing you could use the `startActivityForResult(intent, UNIQUECODE);` and override the `onActivityResult()` method in your `MainActivity`. To make your `toast` look elegant though I would recommend you to use [this](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton) and for further details on this see [this](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/useful-android-libraries-crouton/).

Comment: it seems that Toon Borgers already answered this, but do see the library. It's a really pretty toast implementation.